# Defining template and style together within the button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have WPF button below:

```
<Button Name="btnAdd" Click="btnAdd_Click">                    
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>                          
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <Image Height="20" Width="20" Stretch="UniformToFill" Source="./Resources/Add.png"/>                               
                <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center">Add</Label>
            </StackPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>                        
    </Button.Template>                     
</Button>
```

Now within the wpf button I am trying to add the following style, I mean, combining style with template in the button:

```
<Button>
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource MyStyle}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Simply set both Button.Style and Button.Template inside the Button tag. Or add a Style Setter for the Template property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way could be adding a `Setter` to your `Style` for `Template` *property*. Like this:

```
<Button.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource MyStyle}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <Image Height="20" Width="20" Stretch="UniformToFill" Source="./Resources/Add.png"/>
                        <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center">Add</Label>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Button.Style>
```